# Problems installing URW-Garamond Missing Font Error ugmr8r

Tags: fonts, pdftex, installing

I recently tried to install the URW Garamond Font. On one PC it was effortless, but on the other laptop, it is giving me a lot of issues! When I run the file, I get the following error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./letter.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 7 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./mathdesign.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdugm/mdugm.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdugm/mdugm.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdfont.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdsffont.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdttfont.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdugm/ot1mdugm.fd))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdugm/t1mdugm.fd)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)) (./letter.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdacmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathdesign/mdbcmr.fd) [1{/var/lib/texm
f/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./letter.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+2/600 --dpi 602 md-gmr8t
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for md-gmr8t.
mktexpk: perhaps md-gmr8t is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file md-gmr8t): Font md-gmr8t at 602 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Where did I go wrong? Just going round in circles for the past two days. Any step-by-step illustrative guide on a clean installation?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It might not be a bad idea to show us the file you got the error message from, though in your case that might be of less importance. It would still be helpful if you could provide more detail on what you did and your system (TeXlive 2013 is quite outdated now).

Comment: Just a short addendum, I thought texlive-full installation on Ubuntu would be a cleaner solution. I installed that, but it gave a dpkg errorcode (1) when I did that!

Comment: Moewe, thanks for the response. I just ran the command: {sudo updmap-sys --syncwithtrees} and it resolved the issue. The document was a simple one with just {\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}} in the header.

Comment: This is not the appropriate format for this site. Please familiarize yourself with the way things work out the best here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments.